# Objective c 2D gradient

Tags: objective-c, gradient

I need to make at 2D gradient. I have the first part of it make a gradient vertical direction from a color to a clear color:

```
+ (void)addFadeout:(UIView *) view withColor:(UIColor *)color {
    UIColor * halfClearColor = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:0];

    CALayer *layer = view.layer;
    layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    CAGradientLayer *shineLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    shineLayer.frame = layer.bounds;
    shineLayer.colors = @[
            (id)color.CGColor,
            (id)halfClearColor.CGColor];
    shineLayer.locations = @[
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
    [view.layer insertSublayer:shineLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

But I also need to be able to add multiple colors in the horizontal direction where they either fade together and is shown separately(still with the vertical gradient). I know I could just add them besides each other but that is not what I am looking for.. How would you do it?

It might be something like this but I can't seem to connect the parts:
http://cupsofcocoa.com/tag/gradient/
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html

**Edit 1:**

This is what I got now:

[image: Current gradient]

It might be unclear what I wanted. I also want a gradient along the x-axis between multiple colors. So what I got combined with something like this: (to replace the red color)
[image]

**Solution:**

```
+ (void)addFadeout:(UIView *) view withColors:(NSArray *)colors { //CGColors
    UIColor * someColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:((__bridge CGColorRef)[colors lastObject])];//only alpha channel used with more than one color
    UIColor * halfClearColor = [someColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0];

    CALayer *layer = view.layer;
    layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    CAGradientLayer *transparencyLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    transparencyLayer.frame = layer.bounds;
    transparencyLayer.colors = @[
            (id)someColor.CGColor,
            (id)halfClearColor.CGColor];
    transparencyLayer.locations = @[
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];

    if(colors.count > 1){
        CAGradientLayer * multiColoredLayer = [self getMultiColoredLayerWithColors:colors inLayer:layer];
        multiColoredLayer.mask = transparencyLayer;
        [view.layer insertSublayer:multiColoredLayer atIndex:0];
    }
    else{
        [view.layer insertSublayer:transparencyLayer atIndex:0];
    }
}


+ (CAGradientLayer *)getMultiColoredLayerWithColors:(NSArray *)colors inLayer:(CALayer *)layer{ //CGColors
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = layer.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = colors;
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
    return gradientLayer;
}
```

Comment: What is the result you want, it isn't easy to tell? Should you just be putting another gradient view behind the one you already have?

Comment: So it's like having a gradient at the back with colours, and another gradient in front which fades the colour to white / transparent (which) at the bottom? An individual `CAGradientLayer` can only have a gradient in one direction.

Comment: Yes.. Okay - how is it posible without CAGradientLayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 2 of 'something' as gradients can only be drawn in a single direction at a time. You could do it with 2 `CAGradientLayer`s, one behind the other (or one as a sublayer of the other). Or, you could do it with 2 `CGGradient`s, both drawn into the same context.

---

From your comment, you want to alpha mask. The best way to apply the 'top' layer with transparency is by setting it as the `mask` of the 'bottom' layer:

```
CAGradientLayer *colorLayer = ...;
CAGradientLayer *transparencyLayer = ...;

colorLayer.mask = transparencyLayer;
```

In this case, any colour in the `transparencyLayer` is ignored and only the alpha values are used.

Comment: How can the gradient to transparent work on the other gradient?

Comment: You insert the second gradient at index 1.